# ООП, полиморфизм

Tags: ооп, java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new B(); // ***
    }
}
class A {
  ...
}
class B extends A {
 ...
}
```

кто сможет объяснить плюсы и минусы  выделенной строчки, т.е. почему делается `A a = new B()`, а когда лучше `A a = new А()` или `В a = new B()`, ну или `В a = new B()`?

Comment: В данном случае у этой строки и плюсов и минусов нет.
В каждом конкретном случае могут быть свои плюсы и минусы.

Comment: ну вот это я и прошу, т.е. интересно, когда мне стоит пользоваться каждым из вариантов? где кто кого наследует?

Comment: B наследует A. А вот где нужно использовать - ...
Ну к примеру можно создать Map<Integer,A>. В таком случае в этот мап можно будет пихать и объекты B, но не наоборот.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопрос, `A a = new B()` или же `B a = new B()` конкретно **в этом случае** решается просто.

Если для использования в дальнейшем коде вам достаточно *только того интерфейса, который предоставляет класс `A`*, то всегда лучше использовать `A a = new B()`. Это уменьшает связанность объектов (`coupling`), поскольку весь дальнейший код оперирует только интерфейсом, который предоставляет класс `A`.

Тем более, что в таком случае, вы можете легко написать класс `C extends A` и без проблем подменить запись на `A a = new C()`, **что, разумеется, хорошо.**

В современных `IDE` достаточно часто можно встретить авторефакторинг типа `Use Base Type where possible`, который автоматизирует такие сценарии.

---

Проблема становится намного интереснее в случае интерфейсов и работы на уровне интерфейса. Во многих случаях можно объявить *анонимный объект*, имлпементирующий какой-либо интерфейс своим специальным образом и, например, передать его функции, которая *оперирует с объектами, реализующими этот самый интерфейс.*

Более подробно и с примерами кода смотрите [**здесь**](http://www.artima.com/javaseminars/modules/PolymorphInt/index.html) и, например, *(на более промышленном уровне)* в [**Effective Java.**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)

---

Дальше, кстати говоря, это все эволюционирует в разговоры об [**IoC**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), `Dependency Injection` и других техниках `code decoupling`.

Основной принцип - уменьшение зависимостей и точек соприкосновения кода, работа через интерфейсы и выбор необходимого объекта с некоторым интерфейсом в зависимости от настроек  модуля иньекции / `IoC контейнера`.